# Error installing Apache2 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, installation

I used the command `sudo apt-get install apache2` and get the error below:

any suggestions?

```
# sudo apt-get install apache2

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap ssl-cert
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,285 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,348 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Err http://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main apache2-bin amd64 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main apache2-data all 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]


E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Have you followed the advice of trying to run `apt-get update` ?

Answer (score 3):

Read the suggestion at the end of the error message. Your apt source lists are out of date.

A quick check of the ubuntu package website [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/apache2) revealed that the current version number of apache2 in trusty-updates is 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.**9**

Run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -uf upgrade` and then try the command again.